# Singleton factory: какой это паттерн?

Tags: python, ооп

Доброго времени!

На днях столкнулся с задачей: расширить Singleton так, чтобы одновременно можно было иметь несколько разных Singloton'ов на базе одного класса... саму идею реализовать труда не составило, но и singleton'om это уже назвать сложно т.к по факту экземпляр класса в памяти не один, а несколько...

И собственно сам сабж:  к какому паттерну относится сие чудо? дискуссия в рабочей обстановке и многопоточный Google(ing) так и не привело к чему-то хоть немного похожему описанию...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:u8 -*-
__author__ = '_killed_'

class Singleton(object):
    __instance = {}
    #__tags={}
    def __new__(cls,*a,**k):
        __singleton_name__ = k.get('__singleton__',None)
        if not cls.__instance:
            cls.__instance[__singleton_name__] = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls,*a,**k)
            return cls.__instance[__singleton_name__]
        else:
            if __singleton_name__ not in cls.__instance:
                cls.__instance[__singleton_name__] = super(Singleton, cls).__new__(cls,*a,**k)
                return cls.__instance[__singleton_name__]
            else:return cls.__instance[__singleton_name__]
    def __init__(self,*argc,**kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.__singleton__

single = Singleton()
c1 = [Singleton(__singleton__='c1') for i in xrange(5)]
c2 = [Singleton(__singleton__='c2') for i in xrange(5)]
c3 = [Singleton(__singleton__='c3') for i in xrange(5)]

for i in [c1,c2,c3]:
    print map(str,i)
    print map(id,i)
    print map(hash,i)
    print "*"*30
print single._Singleton__instance
```

Cам код смотрим тут: http://paste.org/52784. P.S: Буду признателен если знатоки проявят заинтересованность.

Comment: меня мучает один вопрос, это я один такой дурак, что питоновский код для меня слабо читаем ?

ЗЫ: да, на питоне не писал

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Multiton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern)

> В разработке программного обеспечения, multiton - это шаблон похожий на singleton, который допускает создание только одного экземпляра класса. Модель multiton расширяет концепцию singleton для управления картой именованных экземпляров как пар ключ-значение.

Comment: благодарствую, нам на глаза это почему то не попалось...

Answer (score 3):

Не люблю притянутую за уши классификацию и стремление все втиснуть в некие "модные" рамки (это я о *паттернах*).

В Вашем случае я бы говорил о пуле объектов.